# Could not find or load main class onjava

Tags: java, tomcat, javac

I have the following code and I am trying to create a connection to a database.
I get an error "*Could not find or load main class onjava*" when I run the command: *java -cp . onjava*

I am able to run the *javac -classpath "C:\CATALINA_HOME\lib*" onjava.java* command
Both of my .class and .java files are in the same directory WEB-INF\classes\com\onjava

**onjava.java**

```
package com.onjava;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.*;

import javax.naming.Context;

public class onjava extends HttpServlet {

  private DataSource datasource;

  public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    try {
      // Look up the JNDI data source only once at init time
      Context envCtx = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
      datasource = (DataSource) ((InitialContext) envCtx).lookup("jdbc/testdb");
    }
    catch (NamingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return datasource.getConnection();
  }

  public void doGet (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException {
    Connection connection=null;
    try {
      connection = getConnection();
      //..<do JDBC work>..
      if (connection != null) {

            String message = "You are connected!";
            System.out.println(message);


        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    } 
    catch (SQLException sqlException) {
      sqlException.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
      if (connection != null) 
        try {connection.close();} catch (SQLException e) {}
      }
    }
  }
```

**EDIT:**

I changed my code and I added the public class. But I am facing the same error when I run it!

```
package src;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Wrapper;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.*;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

public class onjava {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws SQLException, NamingException {

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
        Context initialContext = new InitialContext(prop);
        if ( initialContext == null){
              System.out.print("JNDI problem. Cannot get InitialContext.");
        } else {System.out.print("NO JNDI problemb ");}

        // Get DataSource
        Context envContext = (Context)initialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/testdb");



        System.out.println("\n -------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

        try {



            Connection jdbcConnection = ((Statement) ds).getConnection();
            OracleDataSource ods = ((Wrapper) ds).unwrap(OracleDataSource.class);
            jdbcConnection.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        String message = "You are connected!";
        System.out.println(message);

    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your main class in this code? This only shows onjava class but this is not your main class.

Comment: What do you mean? My main class is in the same folder as my .java. I am following an example on the internet and this is all he has... I know I am new in to this

Comment: Look at Hypino's answer. You need to call the main method or the main class which will in turn allow your program to connect to the DB.

Comment: I think I am missing the main class here.. How can I add it to this code and how can I return "connected" if a connection was made successfully? Thank you

Comment: Easy. Go back to your compiler and create a main class. Once this is done, create an object of your onjava class and use that to call your method of connecting to the database.

Comment: Easy for someone who has experience haha :) Thank you for your time though! would you be able to help me out with the code?

Comment: Just took a look at it. I am recommending you have two classes: one with a main method that will call the other class (which has your method to connect to the DB). That would probably be neater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so from what you told me, you need to have a main class attached to your project. This means going back to your compiler and creating the main method. To add your code, you will need to do something like this in the main class, which I will call `onjavaMain`:

```
public class onjavaMain{

//Main method is this
public static void main(String[] args)
       {
       //create variable of your onjava class
       onjava onJavaConnectToDatabase = new onjava();
       onJavaConnectToDatabase.doGet(argument1,argument2);
       }
}
```

Now this is not the complete answer, but this will give you an idea of what you need to do in order to run your project in command line.

Comment: Awesome! and what should I put for the argumets?

Comment: That I am not sure of, it will need to reference the HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res that it is taking in as parameters in your onjava class, though.

Comment: Thank you for your time! Unfortunately that is where I am stuck. I want to create a database connection and return the "connected" text.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. But you need that main class to begin the connection. Like i mentioned, my answer will give you an idea as to what to do but it is not the complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

When running java like this, you need to explicitly state the main class. Your command should look something more like `java -cp . com.onjava.onjava`. However, I don't see the main method in this class either. You need to point to the main method (ie, signature `public static void main()`).

By the way, it is proper convention to give your classes names that start with a capital letter (Onjava).

Comment: Hi Hypino, thanks for your help. it did not work and I got an error saying: Could not find or load main class com.onjava.onjava Am I missing something?

Comment: Again, you need to replace the `com.onjava.onjava` with the package.classname of the class that has `public static void main()`. Otherwise, Java won't know where code execution is supposed to begin.